# Swift: didReceiveRemoteNotification to be called with no user activity involved (Using Houston ruby gem)

Tags: ios, ruby, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have a small swift app written. I have successfully configured the remote notification services. Here is the code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    println("received notification")
    var remoteServer = RemoteServer()
    remoteServer.sendDataToServer { (success) -> () in
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
    }
}
```

Now, I am using Houston ruby gem to send the notifications. which looks something like this

```
require 'houston'
APN = Houston::Client.production
APN.certificate = File.read("production_certificate.pem")

token = "token here"
notification = Houston::Notification.new(device: token)
notification.content_available = true
notification.alert = "test"
notification.badge = 0
APN.push(notification)
```

I can successfully see the message on the lock screen. But its when I swipe the notification , which opens the app, thats when the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method gets called.

I am wondering if there is a way to fire off `didReceiveRemoteNotification` without the user having to swipe the notification ? (Pretty much no user activity required) ?

I tried setting the alert to nil. But then since no user activity can be detected `didReceiveRemoteNotification` never gets fired off.

How should I handle this scenario? Should I be using `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` , but then how to fire it from the remote server?

UPDATE: the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` does get sent out when the app is currently opened, but as soon as the device is locked. The same isn't getting called.

Thanks